# How to insert a letter into a report class document?

Tags: letters, report

I'd like to insert a letter into a document I make with Report class. How could I do it? This a very MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{A title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Append the pdf file. Or use a package like scrletter.

Comment: Can I customize scrletter in order to treat it like an ordinary document with sections ans subsections?

Comment: Report does have sections and subsections.